# del /q not able to delete locked files

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to delete a log folder and all its content frequently. But when I run

```
del /q <<'folder name'>>
```

I get an error

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

I tried `rd`, `rmdir`, `/F` option but all of them gives the same error. How do I delete the folder and its content?

Comment: You need to close the application that uses that folder (probably the one that writes the log files). As long as it has a file open in that directory, you can't remove the directory.

Comment: Use `RD /S /Q "Folder Name"`, `DEL` is for files.

Comment: @Compo That does not change the problem, that a file is locked.

Comment: I didn't answer the question @geisterfurz007, I provided a comment because they are clearly using `del /q <<'folder name'>>` as their preferred option.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : i do not want to disturb the application, in the background this process removes the generated log files.

Comment: @Shadab: then just delete the _files_ but not the directory

Comment: The following will stop the output, _including any error message_:`DEL /A /F /Q "folder name\*.*" 1>NUL 2>&1`

Comment: @Compo : thanks it worked.

Comment: The various comments and answers show how to hide the error message if a file is locked. But they do not show a method to delete a locked file. I don't think it is possible - the file cannot be deleted until the process releases the lock. One way to remove the lock is to kill the locking process, which is a whole topic unto itself. Another issue is identifying which process has the lock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will stop the output, *including any error message*:

```dos
DEL /A /F /Q "folder name\*.*" 1>NUL 2>&1
```

This answer is due to my confirmed comment.

Answer (score 2):

I would use:

```bat
2> nul rmdir /S /Q "folder_name"
```

So all content of folder `folder_name` is deleted (both files and sub-folders) and the access error message (if any) is suppressed. In case the folder is not accessed by any application, it is deleted.

If you never want to delete the folder `folder_name`, you need to delete its content in two steps:

```bat
rem // Delete files:
del /Q "*.*"
rem // Delete sub-folders:
for /D %%D in ("folder_name") do (
    rmdir /S /Q "%%~D"
)
```

Perhaps you have to reset some file attributes first (for both variants), in case there are files with read-only, hidden and/or system attributes set:

```bat
attrib -R -H -S "folder_name\*.*" /S
```